# When session is considered accessed

Tags: java, session, servlets

Does calling `HttpServletRequest.getSession(boolean create)` cause the last accessed time of the session to be updated? What about `getId()` method or even calling `getLastaccessedtime()`. In brief, what is the criteria of accessing the `HttpSession` that cause the `getLastAccessedTime` to be updated

Answer (score 4):

The Tomcat [javadoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getLastAccessedTime%28%29) says this:

> "Returns the last time the client sent a request associated with this session, as the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970 GMT, and marked by the time the container received the request.
>
> *Actions that your application takes, such as getting or setting a value associated with the session, do not affect the access time.*"

So, based on what the javadoc says,  the answers to your questions are (should be):

> Q: Does calling HttpServletRequest.getSession(boolean create) cause the last accessed time of the session to be updated?

A: According to the javadoc, No.  (But see below)

> Q: What about getId() method or even calling getLastaccessedtime().

A: No.

> Q: In brief, what is the criteria of accessing the HttpSession that cause the getLastAccessedTime to be updated.

A: See above.  It records the time of the last client request for the session.

---

Note that the actual behavior is liable to depend on the Servlet implementation.  For instance, according to the Tomcat 7 source code ([7.0.39.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.geronimo.ext.tomcat/catalina/7.0.39.2/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#Request.getSession%28boolean%29)), a `getSession(boolean)` call *will* update the access time:

1. when the current `Session` is not already cached in the `Request` AND the request's session manager is able to map the sessionid to a valid `Session`, or
2. when `create` is `true` AND a `Session` is created.

It is not clear whether scenario 1. could actually happen in a call from application code, but scenario 2. certainly could.  It means that creating the `Session` counts as an "access" ... which makes sense.

Comment: Does that mean that any request even ajax requests in a secured application will update the session last accessed time? Since authentication do create a session to follow the authenticated user.

Comment: AFAIK, yes it does.  However, see my note about the behavior being implementation dependent.

Answer (score 2):

This pretty much depends on the implementation and configuration of the server. Like tomcat has setting in the source whether to set `lastAccessedTime` at the arrival of request or before sending response back.

Looking at Tomcat 7 source code answers are

> HttpServletRequest.getSession(boolean create) updates lastAccessedTime ?

**Yes**

> getId() updates lastAccessedTime ?

**No**

> getLastaccessedtime() updates lastAccessedTime ?

**No**

Tomcat is updating lastAccessedTime by using `access()` method in the `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession`.

Below is source code for access() method

```
/**
 * Update the accessed time information for this session.  This method
 * should be called by the context when a request comes in for a particular
 * session, even if the application does not reference it.
 */
@Override
public void access() {

    this.thisAccessedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (ACTIVITY_CHECK) {
        accessCount.incrementAndGet();
    }

}
```

This method is called in `HTTPServletRequest` implementation of Tomcat class `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request`'s `getSession(boolean create)` method. Same is true for simple `getSession()` call.

Following is the screenshot of call hierarchy of `access()`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the Servlet Specification:

> The
>   session is considered to be accessed when a request that is part of the session is first
>   handled by the servlet container.

That rules out all methods on the session immediately, as you already have to identify the session to associate the request with it, and it rules in `getSession(boolean)` if it creates a new session or first associates the request with the session.