# how to handle session timeout manually using HandlerInterceptorAdapter in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I want to do some activity on session timeout,I have used HandlerInterceptorAdapter which looks like this

```
package com.practice.security;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class SessionHandelerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    private static final long MAX_INACTIVE_SESSION_TIME = 5 * 10000;
    @Autowired
    private HttpSession session;
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        //long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //request.setAttribute("executionTime", startTime);
        if (this.isUserLogged()) {
            session = request.getSession();
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getLastAccessedTime()
              > MAX_INACTIVE_SESSION_TIME) {

                //Do some more activity

                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                request.logout();
                response.sendRedirect("/userLogin/logout");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isUserLogged(){
        try {
            return !SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
              .getName().equals("anonymousUser");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Issue is when request  comes to preHandle method of interceptor, session's lastAccessTime gets updated to current time. 
I think the reason is before going to prehandle method every request goes to doget method of my custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.I have also used Spring security in my application.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

import com.practice.AppConstant;

public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private Tokenutils tokenUtils;

    //@Autowired
    //private UserDetailsService userDetailService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request , ServletResponse res , FilterChain chain) throws IOException , ServletException{

            tokenUtils=(Tokenutils) WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext()).getBean(Tokenutils.class);

            //userDetailService=WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext()).getBean(UserDetailsService.class);

            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            //response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,"+AppConstant.tokenHeader);

            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
            //String authToken=httpRequest.getHeader(AppConstant.tokenHeader);
            String authToken=httpRequest.getParameter("XAuthToken");
            String userName=this.tokenUtils.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
            if(userName!=null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null){
                //UserDetails userDetails= this.userDetailService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
                UserDetails userDetails=new SpringSecurityUser(1L, userName, null, null, null, AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(""));
                if(this.tokenUtils.validateToken(authToken,userDetails)){
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication= new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, res);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring security then it's better to rely on the session timeout instead of checking the inactive time yourself. Few issues with this approach is - you are implementing security at much deeper level in stack as it should be handled at Filter level which is where Spring security handles it. Secondly as per servlet specs

> The session is considered to be accessed when a request that is part
>   of the session is first handled by the servlet container.

Also the `session.getLastAccessedTime()` is updated anytime when the `request.getSession` is called (atleast this is how it is in Tomcat 7, there could be multiple behaviours as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552875/when-session-is-considered-accessed)) which can be called at any place - any other Filter configured, Servlet, HandlerInterceptor, Controller. And last but very important - `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` will remove the `SecurityContext` from the current thread ( where it was saved by `ThreadLocal`) but it will be still present in the session ( where it will is saved by default) which is not what you actually want.

Another option could be to store the login time in the User Object stored in Spring security context on login and then check for the time and inactivate the session and redirecting to login page afresh.

**UPDATE**:- There is another easy way in which you can write a custom filter like below and register it **before** the Spring security filter in web.xml. 
What we are doing here is saving last access time in session for first visit, then updating the last access time in session on every visit but if it exceeds the inactive time redirect to login page. So basically you are not rely on session object last access time but a user defined variable stored in session. Also we invalidate the current session if inactivity time exceeds. I have tested this filter along with Spring security filters  and it works fine. You can do similar thing in an Spring HandlerInterceptor but I feel this kind of check should be implemented at a place even before Spring security gets involved. But it's a choice.

```
public class InactivityFilter implements Filter {

    private static final long MAX_INACTIVE_SESSION_TIME = 5 * 1000;

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("InactivityFilter.init()");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        System.out.printf("InactivityFilter.doFilter(): requestURI = %s; ", requestURI);

        Long firstAccessTime = (Long) request.getSession().getAttribute("lastAccessTime");

        if (firstAccessTime == null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("lastAccessTime", new Date().getTime());
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }

        if (firstAccessTime != null) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - firstAccessTime > MAX_INACTIVE_SESSION_TIME) {
                request.getSession().invalidate();
                response.sendRedirect("the url for login page");
                return;
            } else {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("lastAccessTime", new Date().getTime());
                chain.doFilter(req, resp);
            }

        }

    }

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("InactivityFilter.destroy()");
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please provide some sample code to meet my above requirement

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to store first access time in session of every user (check if first time is null then set the access time else do not set). This can be done in a global interceptor which runs for each access ( or a filter sitting in front in your application). Then in your spring interceptor handler get the value from session and if found within inactive time range let the user proceed. Else call session.invalidate and redirect to login page. So basically you are not rely on session object last access time but a user defined variable stored in session

Comment: Thank you for your response Shailendra. preHandle method of HandlerInterceptorAdapter  is also called before every request is served so can I apply your given logic in this method only?

Comment: Yes I see no issue in this.