# How Java EE extend session lifetime/timeout

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security, timeout, jsessionid

I have a Java EE session which timeout in 10 minutes if idle. I know any request that hit the server will make it "not idle" and its session will be refreshed.

My question is, how Java EE container handle this underneath?

1) is it because of it detect the existence of the cookies (`JSESSIONID`) in the HTTP request header?

2) **Or** because of calling the `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(false)` does the trick underneath?

I can't find anything in detail after searching many posts.

Why I need to know this, is because I encounter an issue. I have an app which timeout in 10 minutes. But I have a polling ajax running periodically after few seconds too. Which mean, my session will never expire/timeout. The ajax polling contain the cookies (`JSESSIONID`), but I am not sure whether is it the main cause, because I do have Spring Security filter which maybe calling `request.getSession` for every HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time of searching, I think there is no absolute answer, because it depends on the individual implementation.

Based on the specification I found on servlet-4-final-spec:

> 7.6 Last Accessed Times 
>   
> The getLastAccessedTime method of the HttpSession interface allows a servlet to determine the last time the
>   session was accessed before the current request. The session is
>   considered to be accessed when a request that is part of the session
>   is first handled by the servlet container.

So I go find Tomcat [implementation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getLastAccessedTime()):

> long getLastAccessedTime()
>   
> Returns the last time the client sent a request associated with this
>   session, as the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970
>   GMT, and marked by the time the container received the request.
>   Actions that your application takes, such as getting or setting a
>   value associated with the session, do not affect the access time.

Still not very clear, it said "value associated with the session", but not saying the `getSession`.

Then I found [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html#Sessions):

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.ACCESS_SESSION
>
> If this is true, every request that is associated with a session will
>   cause the session's last accessed time to be updated regardless of
>   whether or not the request explicitly accesses the session. Else the default value will be **false**.

So for Tomcat, by default, we have to explicit call `request.getSession` in order to refresh the session, unless we set this Tomcat properties to true.

Reference:

1) [When session is considered accessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552875/when-session-is-considered-accessed)

2) http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Session-timeouts-ignore-quot-periodic-polling-quot-URL-td2159572.html